# How to get DRY on the lines `value: _value(this.from, this.to, line)` below?

Tags: javascript, object, dry

The function `getRegistry()` creates a Registry object with several properties, which share the same structure in JavaScript:

```
'use strict'

function getRegistry(line) {
  return {
    systemId: {
      from: 1, to: 3,
      name: 'system_id',
      value: _value(this.from, this.to, line)
    },
    originUnity: {
      from: 4, to: 7,
      name: 'origin_unity',
      value: _value(this.from, this.to, line)
    },
    // ... similar property definition as above
  }
}

function _value (from, to, line) {
  return line.substring(from - 1, to)
}

module.exports = getRegistry
```

How to change the property definition in the line `value: _value(this.from, this.to, line)` so to remove code duplications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't look sloppy to me... but if you really want to be as code-efficient as possible, this is the only improvement I see:

```
   function getRegistry(line) {
      return {
        systemId: {
          from: 1, to: 3,
          name: 'system_id',
          value: _value(this, line)
        },
        originUnity: {
          from: 4, to: 7,
          name: 'origin_unity',
          value: _value(this, line)
        },
        // ... similar property definition as above
      }
    }

    function _value (obj, line) {
      return line.substring(obj.from - 1, obj.to)
    }
```

Comment: Nice! This work for now, since it is the first object draft.